# iOS Alpha Testing like Google Play

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play

I am a Android Developer and I would like to port my app to iOS. I already registered for the iOS program from apple.

But is there a way to Test a alpha or beta version of my app from a small group of people like in google play store?

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=de

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You might enjoy using [AppBlade](https://appblade.com). It's a tool indie developers, dev shops, and large companies alike use to manage their mobile application testing on iOS, Android, and more.

One thing that you might find convenient would be the ability to upload your project to AppBlade then create a link to recruit testers for your project... share that via social media or email and you should get all the testers you need.

If that's not to your liking, there have been some recent blog posts making their way around that have lists of options, such as [this post on Venturebeat](http://venturebeat.com/2014/03/01/7-alternatives-to-testflight/), and this post on [Joppar Mobile's Site](http://joppar.com/testflight-alternatives/). Maybe those would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) that is good for that. TestFlight is a developer tool used for distributing iOS apps to testers.

Comment: Is that compatible with Phonegap?

Comment: @Rookee If extension of Phonegap app is APK or IPA then you can probably, so try that